# How to set GridView row height?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have a `GridView`, and setting the number of columns and the overal width of the grid layout. Need items with `66dp` x `66dp` size. But somehow items  are squared, but smaller the 66x66. What am I forget?

```
int zz = .. // number of columns comes from outside
gridview.setNumColumns(zz);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)gridview.getLayoutParams();
linearParams.width=66*zz;
gridview.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
```

---

```
<GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:columnWidth="66dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:stretchMode="none"
                android:verticalSpacing="0dp">

            </GridView>
```

---

item prototype

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="66dp" android:layout_height="66dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

shreen shot

[image]

Comment: can you share your screenshot and which device have you test

Comment: added screen shot, Alcatel One Touch

Answer (score 0):

You can Use This..

```
int width = 66*zz;

view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.width, YOUR_HEIGHT));
```

Comment: I get a crash says: `AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams` with your approach. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Probably, you are trying to set linear layouts parameters to list view.

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams` require value in pixel not dp

```
int gridItemWithInDp = 66;
int gridItemWithInPx = (int) (gridItemWithInDp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);

linearParams.width=gridItemWithInPx *zz;
gridview.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the width of gridview in dp either from code or from declared into resource xml

from code:

```
final float density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) ((66 * zz) * density + 0.5f);
```

or from xml

```
int pixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.example_dimen);

gridview.setNumColumns(zz);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams =       (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)gridview.getLayoutParams();
linearParams.width=pixels;
gridview.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
```

Set item prototype width and height MATCH_PARENT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```